# How to use UIWebView and WKWebView intermittently

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am building an application that uses `WKWebView`. My problem is that I want older devices (`IOS 9.0` +) to use the application properly.

Unfortunately `WKWebView` works in an unreliable way on old devices so I think the only solution to this is to identify when running on which `IOS` I run and change to `WKWebView` or `UIWebView` accordingly.

I'm pretty sure I'm not the first developer to come across this problem but I have not found anyone who has solved it. Maybe someone else has realize how to solve it or how to solve the problem in a more professional way?

thank you
yoko

Comment: So the problem is that you don't know how to detect iOS version? Or how to add `UIWebView` if its iOS8, add `WKWebView` if its iOS9 and above?

Comment: if #available(iOS 9.0, *) { // use WKWebView } else { // use UIWebView }

Comment: i cant use `#available(iOS 9.0, *) ` because it's done at compile time , i need it in run time to choose the better widget to my ios version